# @QueryParam returns null for some parameters but not for others

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a little web service that should respond to the following request:

```
[Base]/Measure/measureID/$evaluate-measure?patient=PatientID&periodStart=startDate&periodEnd=endDate
```

I am getting the `measureID` and the `patientID`, but `periodStart` and `periodEnd` are always null.

Here is the call I have been testing:

```
[Base]/Measure/col/$evaluate-measure?patient=Patient-12214&periodStart=2014-01&periodEnd=2014-12
```

The code:

```
@Path("/Measure")
public class MeasureResourceProvider {

  @Path("/{Measure}/$evaluate-measure")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Response processMeasureWithStartAndEnd (@PathParam("Measure") String measureId, @QueryParam("patient") String patientId,
                                @QueryParam("startPeriod") String start, @QueryParam("endPeriod") String end) {
    return handleRequest(measureId, patientId, start, end, null);
  }
}
```

At a loss as to what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: Your parameter names are not matching ;-) periodStart <> startPeriod

Comment: Lol... *sigh* Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names are not the same :)
You are using *periodStart*, but trying to access  *startPeriod*.